# JQuery Autocomplete, populate with data from pHp json

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am returning a JSON encoded array: `echo(json_encode($data));` from php and I would like it to populate the suggest box from JQuery autocomplete. I'm using this:

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
            source : "SearchTest.php",
            maxLength: 5
        });
```

Not sure why this isn't working. After every key press, I would retrieve data and fill the suggest box with that data, I don't want autocomplete to sort and choose for me, I'm doing that server side. It's just a list of strings for now. Being able to customize how the data is presented would be nice as well.

Edit: Changed source to post:

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.post("SearchTest.php", request, response);
            },
            maxLength : 5
        });
```

Getting this error now:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1240' in 
Notice: Undefined index: field in /.../SearchTest.php on line 25
```

Line 25 is : `$whatTheyWantToSearch = $_POST['field'];`

Comment: What error do you get? Can you paste your PHP code, your JS code seems Ok.

Comment: No errors. I just realized I'm not sending anything to the SearchTest.php. How would I post to the server and retrieve the JSON to populate the autocomplete?

Comment: Could you show me your php code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `ajax`

```
var searchRequest = null;
$("#field").autocomplete({
    maxLength: 5,
    source: function(request, response) {
        if (searchRequest !== null) {
            searchRequest.abort();
        }
        searchRequest = $.ajax({
            url: 'SearchTest.php',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                searchRequest = null;
                response($.map(data.items, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.name,
                        label: item.name
                    };
                }));
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            searchRequest = null;
        });
    }
});
```

JSON Response Example in SearchTest.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"items":[{"name":"Ashok"},{"name":"Rai"},{"name":"Vinod"}]}';
?>
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Dy39v/2/)**

**[Remote JSONP Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)**

Comment: Keeps going to .fail function

Comment: That means response is not in proper `JSON` format from SearchTest.php, Answer updated, added `method: 'post',` `JSON` format and Demo Fiddle

Comment: I even tried echo '{"items":[{"name":"Ashok"},{"name":"Rai"},{"name":"Vinod"}]}'; on the php side, but still nothing.

Comment: Also this: $json =  '{"items":[{"name":"Ashok"},{"name":"Rai"},{"name":"Vinod"}]}';
echo json_decode($json);

Comment: Before echo add content type to json by adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` and make sure there is no `echo`, `white space` or `plan text` before `header` function

Comment: Tried it, on fail I'm getting: parsererror 
No conversion from text to application/json

Comment: It's working fine for me, which version of `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` you are using? Try
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm getting this in the responsetext: Undefined index: field

Comment: Alright I commented out the line where I obtain the query from JQuery in php and now I can send your data fine. But I can't obtain the query from the user.

Comment: The issue was not the format of the json, rather not being able to receive the query properly

Comment: Use `$user_entered_text = $_POST['term']` to get what user have entered in field input or change `{term: request.term}` to `{field: request.term}` then you can access user input like this `$field = $_POST['field']`;

Comment: GREAT! Why did I have to change it to term?

Comment: Also, how would I make something happen when a user selects it or presses enter

Comment: Please see `Autocomplete event documentation for that ` http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 3):

the proper json format for this from php:

```
<?php
   echo '[ {"name1":"val1"},{"name2":"val2"} ]'; 
?>
```

From js wich means []-array of {} objects.

In my case for autocomlete widjet this works fine:

```
    $response="[";
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        if($response !="[")$response.=",";
        $response.='{"label":"'.$row["fio"].'","value":"'.$row["id"].'"}';
    }
    $response.="]";

    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something wrong with the source parameter. Should it be '/Searchtest.php'?

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this is the best way. json_encode do all work for you.

```
    $result = $_mysqli->query(...);
    $rs = array();
    $pos = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rs[$pos]["n1"] = $row["n1"];
        $rs[$pos]["n2"] = $row["n2"];
        ...
        $rs[$pos++]["nn"] = $row["nn"];

    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this solution is: We need to use item.label name because the AJAX will return the value in list format so we need to extract the value as shown in the below example. Please let me know if this solution works?

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Ajax</title>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                 $(function() { 
                    $("#myname").autocomplete({
                      source: 'emp.php',
                      select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#myname").val(ui.item.label);
                        $("#myid").val(ui.item.id);
                    },
                       minLength: 0,
                       autoFocus: true,
                    }); 
                });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ajax Testing</h2>
        <input  name="myname" id="myname" type="text">
        <input  name="myid" id="myid" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
-------------- Below is the code of PHP for emp.php page --------------------------
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$query  = "SELECT myname as label , myid as id  FROM emp WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name";
$rsTable = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query,array('%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%'));
while ($row_rsTable = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsTable, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $emparray[] = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $row_rsTable);
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes