# auto complete text box in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i`m trying to make a auto complete text box in php.
here is my  JavaScript code

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').autocomplete({
source : 'search-job.php',
minLength:2
}); 
});
</script>
```

here is my html code

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control input-lg col-xs-4" name="search">
```

here is my search-job.php

```
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['term']))
exit ();
$rs=  mysql_query("select * from jobs where `title` like '%"  . ucfirst($_REQUEST['term']). "%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,10") or      die(mysql_error());
$data=  array();
while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$data[]=array(
'label'=>$row['title'],
'value'=>$row['title']
);
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

i`m getting correct values in search-job.php. but it is not catching by html
but when i run code nothing happened? why is that?

this is how it`s looks on network tab
[image: according to this it is not passing values to term correctly]

Comment: What debugging have you done? Check your network console to see if the JS is firing a request to the server and see what is returned from the server.

Comment: when i run search-job.php it is return values correctly.

Comment: In your browser press F12 and click on the "Network" tab. Is the javascript firing off a request?

Comment: May i think the problem is in jquery library initialize two times

Comment: try adding the correct header to your search-job.php  ... header('Content-Type: application/json also there is no need to call flush(); output is flushed at the end of execution of the script.  Also think of escaping the query inputs too, one would say that is a wise idea.  And lastly your url is relative are you sure it's going where you think it is going.

Comment: @stevenw00 yes i check it.JavaScript is firing.

Comment: @ Artisitic i add the header. but still same issue

Comment: I think json encoding is the problem. check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764554/jquery-autocomplete-populate-with-data-from-php-json

Comment: Can you pls post the result of  "echo json_encode($data); " here.

Comment: @cartina i`m getting following result                                             [{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"},{"label":"Associate UX Enginner","value":"Associate UX Enginner"}]

Comment: I have posted the answer below. {"label":"UX Enginner","value":"UX Enginner"} needs to be {"UX Enginner" : "UX Enginner"}.
I tested it with following code in serach-job.php: 
$array= array();
$array['label1']='test1';
$array['label2']='test2';

echo json_encode($array);

Answer (score 0):

The array format you are passing is wrong.

```
$data[]=array(
'label'=>$row['title'],
'value'=>$row['title']
);
```

should be

```
$data[$row['title']]= >$row['title'];
OR simply
$data[]= >$row['title'];
```

and

replace

```
source : 'search-job.php',
```

with

```
source: 'search-job.php?term='+document.getElementById('search').value,
```

Comment: now i`m getting warning msg "Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\xampp\htdocs\koko\search-job.php on line 9"

Comment: you are not passing the search term to search-job.php file. Please check the changes in updated answer.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i make the changest same result again

Comment: what is the purpose of exit (); here?  echo $_REQUEST['term']  to see if you ara getting serach term.