# jQuery autocomplete is showing empty results

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this PHP script to get all patient name from my database:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('connection.php');
header("Content-type:application/json");
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];

$res = array();
$getPatients = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clinic_id = :cid  ORDER BY patient_id DESC";

$execGetPatients = $conn->prepare($getPatients);
$execGetPatients->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execGetPatients->execute();
$getPatientsResult = $execGetPatients->fetchAll();

$i = 0;
foreach($getPatientsResult as $result)
{
    $res[$i] = $result;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

And I have a text box where I want to display the `patient_name` as autocomplete using `jquery-ui` autocomplete library.

Here is my jQuery script:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $( "#searchTxt" ).autocomplete({
      source: "../php/autoComplete.php"
    });
  })
```

I can see that if a type a name at the network tab I can see a returned array:

[image]

But at the text box I see that the autocomplete are empty like in the following image:

[image]

**And it is showing 2 white boxes instead of one that of the returned array**

Comment: You have to parse the json array using `JQuery.parseJSON() ` then set the each result on auto complete form and it can be an array that could be build from parsed json data.

Comment: I didn't know what do you mean

Comment: can you try what i posted in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1s2Ew4YE)

Comment: I am saying you are giving the whole json array to auto complete source that will won't work so you have to write a code to parse json data and then give the source to auto complete of input..does it makes Sense..

Comment: See this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764554/jquery-autocomplete-populate-with-data-from-php-json?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is nice plugin for that kind of results: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: I will definitely try it now

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the data you have passed, it seems there are multiple columns, you need to specify `label` and `value` or it should be simple array (as per your code it should be this kind of data)like

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",

];
```

You can check more about [custom field passing](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter `typeahead.js` is the best option to implement this feature.

Please take a look into this to achieve it with `PHP`, `AJAX`, and `TypeAhead.js`

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#searchTxt").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      var textVal=$("#searchTxt").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/php/autoComplete.php', // Please add full URL here
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'term=' + textVal,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          process(data);
          console.log(textVal);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

link to [TypeAhead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I added the `typeahead` library and add your script with my correct url, and can't see anything

Comment: still the same PHP script but I changed a line to: `$searchTxt = '%'.$_POST['term'].'%';`

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941988/typeahead-data-is-not-shown-at-the-text-box-and-no-results-at-the-network-tab

Comment: OK Let me check given link

Comment: Added answer there @droidnation

Answer (score 0):

Because you need label and value filed in your json array so your sql would be,

```
$getPatients = "SELECT *, name as label, id as value FROM patient WHERE clinic_id = :cid  ORDER BY patient_id DESC";
```