# Typeahead data is not shown at the text box and no results at the network tab

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead.js

I was working on a script using jquery ui autocomplete, but it seems not working, so someone add a script to help me using typeahead.js library, [here is his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940474/jquery-autocomplete-is-showing-empty-results/44940883#44940883):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#searchTxt").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      var textVal=$("#searchTxt").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/php/autoComplete.php', // Please add full URL here
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'term=' + textVal,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          process(data);
          console.log(textVal);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I added it like it is and changed my PHP script to:

```
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];

$searchTxt = '%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%';
$res = array();
$getPatients = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clinic_id = :cid and patient_name_en LIKE :searchTxt OR dob LIKE :searchTxt OR patient_id LIKE :searchTxt OR patient_phone LIKE :searchTxt OR unhcr_registration_number LIKE :searchTxt ORDER BY patient_id DESC";

$execGetPatients = $conn->prepare($getPatients);
$execGetPatients->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execGetPatients->bindValue(':searchTxt', $searchTxt);
$execGetPatients->execute();
$getPatientsResult = $execGetPatients->fetchAll();

$i = 0;
foreach($getPatientsResult as $result)
{
    $res[$i] = $result;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

I added the libraries (I am using `bootstrap 4` so I downloaded the `typeaheadjs.css` library for it):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/typeaheadjs.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

Now when I type in the searchTxt text box: I can't see any output at the network tab neither at the text box as results. (No errors at the console).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this demo #5

```
$('#demo5').typeahead({
    ajax: { 
            url: '/cities/list',
            triggerLength: 1 
          }
});
```

`autocomplete.php` should return `json` format of data as below

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Alex'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Terry'
  }
]
```

Demo [link](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/)

Documentation [link](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/#docs)

Github [Link](https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead)

Hope you will get it.